# TabView resets to default when selecting data using Control object

Tags: dynamic

I have 3 drop down boxes on one of the tabs in my `TabView`. Two of the drop down boxes results are used in a `Select` statement to change data fed to the graph and these work perfectly. The other drop down box result is used in a `Part` statement and when used causes the `TabView` to refresh and display the default screen. I have tried everything to stop this from happening but I need help!

```
ImputeMissingPairs[data_, maxpoints_] := 
 Module[{missingpoints, plotdata}, 
  missingpoints = Complement[Range[maxpoints], data[[All, 1]]];
  plotdata = data;
  Sort[Partition[
    Flatten[AppendTo[plotdata, 
      Transpose[{missingpoints, Table[NULL, {Length[missingpoints]}]}]]], 2]]]

vlookup[data1_, data2_, pk1_: 1, col1_: {2}, pk2_: 1] := 
 Module[{look}, look[val_, table_, pk2l_] := Select[table, #[[pk2l]] == val &];
  Join[#, Check[look[#[[pk1]], data2, pk2][[1, col1]], 
       ConstantArray[Null, Length@col1]] // Quiet] & /@ data1]
SelectorName[Name_] := Style[Name, FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 11];
SelectorName[List_] := Style[List, FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 11];

MonthlyFuel = {{"Year", "Month", "Generator", "SFC", "Base_SFC", "Tar_SFC", 
    "Rated_SFC", "Eff", "Base_Eff", "Tar_Eff", "Rated_Eff", "Base_Eff_%_Var", 
    "Tar_Eff_%_Var", "Rated_Eff_%_Var", "Fuel", "Base_Fuel", "Tar_Fuel", 
    "Rated_Fuel", "Base_Fuel_%_Var", "Tar_Fuel_%_Var", "Rated_Fuel_%_Var", 
    "Base_Fuel_Var", "Tar_Fuel_Var", "Rated_Fuel_Var", "Power", "Energy", 
    "%_Loading", "Running_Time", "Fuel Mix", "Baseline Fuel Mix", 
    "Baseline Null"}, {2012.`, 1.`, "All", 202.3254481`, 217.4737427`, "NULL",
     "NULL", 41.49001792`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 0.`, "NULL", 
    3.180824733`*^6, 3.41897604`*^6, "NULL", "NULL", 6.965574044`, "NULL", 
    "NULL", 238151.3076`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.462483111`, 15721.328`, 
    82.06110907`, 3523.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 1.`, 1, 199.300316`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 42.11978505`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 543881.9923`, 593476.4924`, "NULL", "NULL", 8.356607334`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 49594.50009`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.641083333`, 2728.957`, 
    85.34540885`, 588.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 1.`, 2, 201.5296348`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.6538564`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 557357.613`, 601453.2118`, "NULL", "NULL", 7.33150941`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 44095.59882`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.54127422`, 2765.636`, 
    83.51000772`, 609.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 1.`, 3, 202.0456397`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.5474765`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 566118.5474`, 609347.0737`, "NULL", "NULL", 7.094237122`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 43228.5263`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.412494488`, 2801.934`, 
    81.1418626`, 635.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 1.`, 4, 199.4107549`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 42.096458`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 498827.5987`, 544012.3071`, "NULL", "NULL", 8.305824679`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 45184.70846`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.451081851`, 2501.508`, 
    81.85144999`, 562.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 1.`, 5, 222.3856501`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 37.74742869`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 90746.91076`, 88742.55291`, "NULL", "NULL", -2.2586209`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", -2004.357847`, "NULL", "NULL", 3.849632075`, 408.061`, 
    70.79132173`, 106.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 1.`, 6, 199.8990389`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.99363095`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 351809.1151`, 382739.4339`, "NULL", "NULL", 8.081299182`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 30930.31874`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.251048309`, 1759.934`, 
    78.17301047`, 414.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 1.`, 7, 207.6301566`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 40.42999632`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 572082.9552`, 599204.9683`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.526333141`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 27122.01306`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.524298851`, 2755.298`, 
    83.19784573`, 609.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 2.`, "All", 201.8764651`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.58229371`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 2.877346267`*^6, 3.099654342`*^6, "NULL", "NULL", 
    7.172027919`, "NULL", "NULL", 222308.0748`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.341457508`, 
    14253.005`, 79.83555551`, 3283.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 2.`, 1, 
    199.6444509`, 217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 42.04718154`, 38.6`, "NULL", 
    "NULL", 100.`, 0.`, "NULL", 468983.5816`, 510866.2641`, "NULL", "NULL", 
    8.198365289`, "NULL", "NULL", 41882.68247`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.465958175`, 
    2349.094`, 82.12501241`, 526.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 2.`, 2, 
    202.1588443`, 217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.52421082`, 38.6`, "NULL", 
    "NULL", 100.`, 0.`, "NULL", 502980.706`, 541084.8931`, "NULL", "NULL", 
    7.042182766`, "NULL", "NULL", 38104.18709`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.43502139`, 
    2488.047`, 81.55611236`, 561.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 4.`, 3, 
    203.6430766`, 217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.22156572`, 38.6`, "NULL", 
    "NULL", 100.`, 0.`, "NULL", 457417.784`, 488483.8665`, "NULL", "NULL", 
    6.359694681`, "NULL", "NULL", 31066.08248`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.319565385`, 
    2246.174`, 79.43297875`, 520.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 2.`, 4, 
    200.2254036`, 217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.92518189`, 38.6`, "NULL", 
    "NULL", 100.`, 0.`, "NULL", 426474.103`, 463212.5477`, "NULL", "NULL", 
    7.931228308`, "NULL", "NULL", 36738.44471`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.251437126`, 
    2129.97`, 78.18016046`, 501.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 2.`, 5, 205.5034775`,
     217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 40.84839133`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`,
     0.`, "NULL", 484094.6778`, 512292.4569`, "NULL", "NULL", 5.504234688`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 28197.77912`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.244418018`, 2355.652`, 
    78.05108529`, 555.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 2.`, 6, 200.0893227`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.95369525`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 531605.3161`, 577792.9385`, "NULL", "NULL", 7.993801811`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 46187.62238`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.327100977`, 2656.84`, 
    79.57155162`, 614.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 2.`, 7, 212.6523627`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 39.475162`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 5790.098532`, 5921.375066`, "NULL", "NULL", 2.216994067`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 131.2765339`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.538`, 27.228`, 
    83.44979772`, 6.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 3.`, "All", 205.0531823`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 40.93809407`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 2.741012941`*^6, 2.907042632`*^6, "NULL", "NULL", 
    5.711291951`, "NULL", "NULL", 166029.6919`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.147479677`, 
    13367.327`, 76.26847513`, 3223.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 3.`, 1, 
    200.4231089`, 217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.88382523`, 38.6`, "NULL", 
    "NULL", 100.`, 0.`, "NULL", 580495.2711`, 629879.8572`, "NULL", "NULL", 
    7.840318348`, "NULL", "NULL", 49384.58601`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.27190118`, 
    2896.349`, 78.55647628`, 678.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 3.`, 2, 204.121885`,
     217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 41.12487237`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`,
     0.`, "NULL", 452499.2317`, 482097.7501`, "NULL", "NULL", 6.139526332`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 29598.51831`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.271308285`, 2216.809`, 
    78.54557347`, 519.`, "", "", ""}, {2012.`, 4.`, 3, 206.0458434`, 
    217.4737427`, "NULL", "NULL", 40.74086781`, 38.6`, "NULL", "NULL", 100.`, 
    0.`, "NULL", 433097.8545`, 457118.716`, "NULL", "NULL", 5.254840956`, 
    "NULL", "NULL", 24020.86151`, "NULL", "NULL", 4.280955193`, 2101.949`, 
    78.72297156`, 491.`, "", "", ""}};

FuelDropDown = {{"Generator", "Measure/Metric", "ChartType", "Comparison", 
    "Year"}, {1.`, "SFC", "RunChart", "Baseline", 2011.`}, {2.`, "FCE", 
    "Variance", "Target", 2012.`}, {3.`, "Fuel", "", "Rated", 2013.`}, {4.`, 
    "Power", "", "", ""}, {5.`, "Energy Produced", "", "", ""}, {6.`, 
    "% Loading", "", "", ""}, {7.`, "Running Hrs", "", "", ""}, {"All", 
    "Fuel Mix", "", "", ""}};

MonthlyFuelHeadings = Part[MonthlyFuel, 1];
DropDownHeadings = Part[FuelDropDown, 1];
GeneratorList = Rationalize[Part[FuelDropDown, 2 ;;, 1]];
MetricList = Part[FuelDropDown, 2 ;;, 2];
YearList = Part[FuelDropDown, 2 ;;, 5];

Part[MonthlyFuel, ;; , 3] = Rationalize[Part[MonthlyFuel, ;; , 3]];
Part[MonthlyFuel, ;; , 3] = 
  Part[MonthlyFuel, ;; , 3] /. n_Integer /; n == 8. -> "All";

(* Initialise variables that will be used later on *)

DropDownYearSelection = 2012.;
FirstGenerator = GeneratorList[[1]];
FirstMetric = MetricList[[1]];
FirstYear = YearList[[2]];
DropDownMetricSelection = MetricList[[1]];
DropDownGeneratorSelection = 1;

(* Create the drop down boxes and their headings *)

DropDownGenerator = Control[{DropDownGeneratorSelection, GeneratorList}];
DropDownMetric = Control[{DropDownMetricSelection, MetricList}];
DropDownYear = Control[{DropDownYearSelection, YearList}];
GenHead = SelectorName["Generator"];
MetricHead = SelectorName["Metric"];
YearHead = SelectorName["Year"];

(* Store the column numbers corresponding to the various drop down options *)

MappingMetricsToColumnsWD = {5, 9, 16, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30};
MappingMetricsToColumnsM = {4, 8, 15, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29};
MetricUnitList = {"g/kWh", "%", "kg", "MW", "MWh", "%", "hrs", "%"};
Tab2Headings = {"Specific Fuel Consumption", "Efficiency", "Fuel Consumption",
    "Power", "Energy Produced", "Percent Loading", "Running Hours", 
   "Fuel Mix"};

(* Convert the user selection to the appropriate column number *)

MetricPosition := 
 Position[MetricList, _?(# == DropDownMetricSelection &)] // Flatten
ColumnInDataM := Part[MappingMetricsToColumnsM, MetricPosition]
ColInDataM := FromDigits[ColumnInDataM]
HeadingTab2 := Part[Part[Tab2Headings, MetricPosition], 1]
ColumnInDataPageHeading := Part[Tab2Headings, MetricPosition]

(* Extract the relevant data sets for plotting *)

MOYGraphData := 
 Select[Part[MonthlyFuel, 
   2 ;;, ;;], #[[3]] == DropDownGeneratorSelection && #[[1]] == 
     DropDownYearSelection &]
MOYGraphData1a := 
 Partition[Riffle[Part[MOYGraphData, ;; , 2], 
   Part[MOYGraphData, ;; , ColInDataM]], 2]


(* Input missing pairs into the data sets *)

MOYGraphData1b := Rationalize[MOYGraphData1a];

(* I now use the function to impute my missing data pairs. *)
MOYGraphData1 := ImputeMissingPairs[MOYGraphData1b, 12];
MOYGraph := Dynamic[ListLinePlot[Tooltip /@ Sort[N[MOYGraphData1]]]]

Tab2 := Column[{Grid[{{YearHead, GenHead, MetricHead}, {DropDownYear, 
       DropDownGenerator, DropDownMetric}}], 
    Column[{HeadingTab2, MOYGraph}, Alignment -> Center]}, Alignment -> Left];

Dashboard := 
 TabView[{"Introduction" -> "IntroPage", "Fuel & Energy" -> Tab2, 
   "Generator Loading" -> "Tab3"}, 1]

(* Displaying the dashboard *)

Dynamic[Dashboard]
```

Comment: You're over cooking it. No need for a dynamic around the tab view as far as I can see -- admittedly after very brief look. Just do this at the end `TabView[{"Introduction" -> "IntroPage", 
  "Fuel & Energy" -> 
   Column[{Grid[{{YearHead, GenHead, MetricHead}, {DropDownYear, 
        DropDownGenerator, DropDownMetric}}], 
     Column[{HeadingTab2, MOYGraph}, Alignment -> Center]}, 
    Alignment -> Left], "Generator Loading" -> "Tab3"}, 1]`

Comment: Yes! Thanks I had no idea this was the problem. I have been sifting throught the full code (much more that what appears above) and was about to give up. Thanks again.

Comment: Does either of the following give what you need: (1) use `Dashboard` instead of `Dynamic[Dashboard]`? or (2) define `Dashboard` with `Set`instead of `SetDelayed`: that is, `Dashboard= TabView[...]; Dynamic[Dashboard]`?

Comment: I realise that using set delayed and dynamic is not necessary and are kind of double-refreshing things.

Comment: Lara, exactly:)

Comment: btw, just noticed [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17442/125) you posted a while back. Aren't these questions the same?

Comment: @kguler looks like an exact duplicate. I voted to close the earlier one rather than this one because the earlier one has no activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Dashboard` instead of `Dynamic[Dashboard]` in the last line

and/or

Define `Dashboard` with `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, that is, change the last two lines to

```
   Dashboard= TabView[...]; 
   Dynamic[Dashboard] (* or just Dashboard *)
```